# MFCC Gender Classification Issue

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, speech-recognition, k-means, mfcc

I'm working on gender estimation from speech signal and I completed MFCC feature extraction. So now I'm trying estimate gender from this features. But I have frames for an audio file and I extracted 13 coefficients for each frame. I'm thinking about to use K Means algroithm for male or female classification but I have not only 1 vector. For example I have 250 frame and 13 coefficients for each frame. So I have 250x13 array. How can I use K Means on an audio file which is divided 250 frames? Should I classify each frame? I hope I can explain my question correctly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Isn't there anybody who have an idea about this topic?

Comment: Kmeans can be applied to all vectors but for gender it is not a great idea, its better to use GMM.